# why $scope variable inside directive is not getting updated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, highmaps

I have made a directive for highmaps using angular, map is getting rendered. I need to pass the final configured object back to controller. Hence i am assigning like this in directive,

```
  $timeout(function() {
      scope.mapconfigured = mapConfig;
   });
```

Initially i defined the controller like this,

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, DB) {
    $scope.mydata = DB.getStatesData();
    $scope.mapconfigured = {};
}
```

But the **mapconfigured** variable is not getting updated inside the directive and also the controller is not printing what i exactly needed.

I am also initially assigning the mapconfigured variable to the directive

```
  <my-map mapconfigured="mapconfigured" mydata="mydata" header="'Highmap Demo'"></my-map>
```

what is the issue here? Here is the **[APPLICATION](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sajeetharan/9rjgLj67/1/)**

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

I need to assign the **mapConfig** object to **mapconfigured** variable of scope inside my controller.

Comment: Wait. So mapconfigured must be an empty dictionary? Becouse `DB.getStatesData()` impys you are loading data async, then you need to make a callback for it.

Comment: I have put an empty object so it does not matter

Comment: ```also the controller is not printing what i exactly needed.``` So what is it printing?

Comment: @IvRRimUm Hope you got my question, its printing empty {}. instead  i want to print the mapConfig object

Comment: And at witch time does the {} become mapConfig object? Can you post the code?

Comment: Whats the content of `mapConfig` ?

Comment: All the code is there in the link I have put

Comment: Okey, will look at this now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123604/discussion-between-ivrrimum-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: why mapConfigured , when you have delared it as mapconfigured? Typo in "C"

Comment: In the code it is correct check the link

Comment: @Ivan yes you are right! i was spending so much time on it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Ivan mentioned in comments it was a typo , scope variable i declared in the controller as 'mapconfigured' but in directive i assigned to  'mapConfigured', changing like this worked

```
<my-map mapconfigured="mapconfigured" mydata="mydata" header="'Highmap Demo'"></my-map>

$timeout(function() {
   scope.mapconfigured = mapConfig;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

That because you used **mapconfigured** in scope directive, and in the link directive you tried to define **mapConfigured** with data.

> Replace with this code:

```
  $timeout(function() {
      scope.mapconfigured = mapConfig;
  });
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan An answer in the comments is hard to find and let this question appear as unanswered. I think you should even even write and accept your answer if the person that helped you in the comments doesn't.